# Setting host on DS.RESTAdapter removing ember-simple-auth headers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-simple-auth

I'm using the ember-cli-simple-auth with ember-cli and everything it working great, until I try and set a new host on DS.RESTAdapter application wide.

As soon as I set

```
// adapters/application.js
exports default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```

or even using reopen() it clears all the headers set by ember-simple-auth.

Am I not setting this up right in ember-cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a different domain for the REST API you need to configure that for OAuth 2.0 authenticator (assuming you're using that) and also make sure you have CORS enabled on the server side. You can find a tutorial here: http://log.simplabs.com/post/90339547725/using-ember-simple-auth-with-ember-cli.

Comment: that part is working great. It's when SimpleAuth.Authorizers.OAuth2 appends the token to a request (Authorization: Bearer <access_token>). Setting a new url in the RESTAdapter is wiping that out.

Comment: You mean `SimpleAuth.Authorizers.OAuth2#authorize` is called and adds the header and that header is later removed? It's more likely I guess that you have not whitelisted the REST API's domain (see here: http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Configuration-crossOriginWhitelist) so that `SimpleAuth.Authorizers.OAuth2#authorize` is never called.

Comment: @marcoow thanks a million! I was tearing my hair out of this one. I wasn't aware of the whitelisting config option and completely overlooked it